# Delete document with async/await in Firestore V9

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, expo

I'm using Firestore v9 within Expo/React Native. I can't properly delete a document using **async/await** and **deleteDoc** function. The document removes fine but my app doesn't wait for the completed operation as I expect. It behaves asynchronously.

This is the call code

```
showDeleteConfirmation(data)
{
    Alert.alert(
        this.title,
        this.message,
        [
          {text: "Yes", onPress: () => this.deleteDococument(data)},
          {text: "No", style: 'cancel'},
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
    )
}

async deleteDococument(data)
{
    const isDataDeleted = await deleteDocFirestore(data)
    console.log(isDataDeleted) // i get undefined
}
```

deleteDocFirestore function

```
const deleteDocFirestore = async (user) => {
    try {

    const docUserRef = doc(db, "users", user.UserId);
    
    const userDeleted = await deleteDoc(docUserRef);

    return userDeleted
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error`, error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`deleteDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#deletedoc) function returns `void` so you can simply return `true` from `deleteDocFirestore` function or `false` if an error is thrown.